# Display Excerpts of Posts in Wordpress Blog

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I have been searching for the answer to my problem and I continually come up with replacing

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

with

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

in the index.php file. However, the theme we are using does not contain this line. Anyone have any insight? Here is the code in our index.php file:

```
    <?php $t =& peTheme(); ?>
<?php $content =& $t->content; ?>
<?php $meta =& $content->meta(); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section class="section-blog section-index" id="<?php $content->slug(); ?>">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns text-center">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row blog-main">

        <div class="large-9 columns blog-left">

            <?php $t->content->loop(); ?>

        </div>

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </div>

</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Source of PeThemeContent.php:

```
<?php

class PeThemeContent {



protected $master;
    protected $loops = array();
    protected $current = false;
    protected $blogLoop = false;
    protected $cols = 0;

    public function __construct(&$master) {
        $this->master = &$master;
        add_filter("pe_post_thumbnail",array(&$this,"post_thumbnail_filter"));  
        add_filter("wp_tag_cloud",array(&$this,"wp_tag_cloud_filter"));
        add_filter("widget_tag_cloud_args",array(&$this,"widget_tag_cloud_args_filter"));
        add_filter("previous_post_link",array(&$this,"strip_rel_filter"));
        add_filter("next_post_link",array(&$this,"strip_rel_filter"));
        add_filter("the_category",array(&$this,"strip_rel_filter"));
        add_filter("excerpt_more",array(&$this,"excerpt_more_filter"));
        add_filter("the_content_more_link",array(&$this,"the_content_more_link_filter"));
        add_filter("edit_post_link",array(&$this,"edit_post_link_filter"));
    }

    public function instantiate() {
    }

    public function loop($name = "") {
        $view = new PeThemeViewBlog;
        $conf = (object) array("settings" => (object) array("layout" => $name));
        $conf->settings->pager = "yes";
        $conf->settings->media = "yes";
        $view->output($conf);
    }

    public function have_posts() {
        if ($this->current) {
            //print_r($this->current);
            $res = $this->current->have_posts();
        } else {
            $res = have_posts();
        }
        return $res;
    }

    public function idx() {
        return $this->wpq->current_post;
    }

    public function last() {
        return $this->wpq->post_count-1;
    }

    public function count() {
        return $this->wpq->post_count;
    }

    public function is_single() {
        return $this->current ? false : is_single();
    }


    public function the_post() {
        if ($this->current) {
            $res = $this->current->the_post();
            $GLOBALS["more"] = false;
        } else {
            $res = the_post();
        }
        return $res;
    }

    public function beginRow($markup) {
        $cols = $this->cols;
        $idx = $this->wpq->current_post;
        if ($cols > 0 && ($idx % $cols) == 0) {
            echo $markup;
        }
    }

    public function endRow($markup = "</div>") {
        $cols = $this->cols;
        $idx = $this->wpq->current_post;
        $last = $this->wpq->post_count-1;
        if ($cols > 0 && (($idx == $last) || ($idx % $cols) == ($cols-1))) {
            echo $markup;
        }
    }


    public function looping($cols = 0) {
        if ($this->have_posts()) {
            $this->cols = $cols;
            $this->the_post();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function &wpq() {
        global $wp_query;
        return $wp_query;
    }

    public function &__get($what) {
        switch ($what) {
        case "wpq":
            if ($this->current) {
                return $this->current;
            }
            return $this->wpq();
        case "qv":
            return $this->wpq()->query_vars;
        case "page":
            $which = (is_front_page() && !is_home()) ? "page" : "paged";
            $page = isset($this->qv[$which]) ? intval($this->qv[$which]) : 0;
            return $page;
        }
    }

    public function title() {
        the_title();
    }

    public function titleAttribute() {
        the_title_attribute();
    }

    public function getLink() {
        $link = get_permalink();

        global $post;
        if (isset($post) && $post->post_type === "attachment") {
            $link = $this->get_origImage();
        }
        return $link;
    }

    public function link() {
        echo $this->get_link();
    }

    public function twitterShareLink() {
        $link = "http://twitter.com/home?status=";
        $link .= urlencode(get_the_title()." - ");
        $link .= get_permalink();
        echo esc_attr($link);
    }

    public function facebookShareLink() {
        $link = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=";
        $link .= get_permalink();
        echo esc_attr($link);
    }

    public function filter($tax,$sep = "",$aclass="label",$template = '%s') {

        if (is_array($tax) && isset($tax[1]) && is_a($tax[1],"PeThemeDataLoop")) {
            $loop = $tax[1]->main->loop;

            $ids = array();
            $n = count($loop);
            for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) {
                $ids[] = $loop[$i]->id;
            }

            $terms = wp_get_object_terms($ids,$tax[0]);

        } else if ($this->have_posts()) {
            $ftax = in_array($tax,array('post_tag','category')) ? strtr($tax,array('post_tag'=>'tag','category' => 'category_name')) : $tax;

            if (!empty($this->wpq->query[$ftax])) {

                $slugs = explode(",",$this->wpq->query[$ftax]);
                $terms = array();
                if (!empty($slugs)) { 
                    foreach ($slugs as $slug) {
                        $term = get_term_by('slug',$slug,$tax);
                        if (!empty($term) && !empty($term->term_id)) {
                            $terms[] = $term;
                        }

                    } 
                }
            } else {
                $posts =& $this->wpq->posts;
                $ids = array();
                $n = count($posts);
                for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) {
                    $ids[] = $posts[$i]->ID;
                }
                $terms = wp_get_object_terms($ids,$tax);                
            }
        } else {
            $terms = array();
        }

        $seen = array();
        // to get all terms
        //$terms = get_terms($tax);

        $output = "";
        $buffer = "";

        if (is_array($terms) && count($terms) > 0) {
            $buffer = apply_filters("pe_theme_filter_item",sprintf('<a class="%s active" data-category="" href="#">%s</a>%s',$aclass,__("All",'Pixelentity Theme/Plugin'),"$sep\n"),$aclass,"",__("All",'Pixelentity Theme/Plugin'));
            $output = sprintf($template,$buffer);

            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $id = $term->term_id;
                if (isset($seen[$id])) continue;
                $seen[$id] = true;
                $buffer = apply_filters("pe_theme_filter_item",sprintf('<a class="%s" data-category="%s" href="#">%s</a>%s',$aclass,$term->slug,$term->name,"$sep\n"),$aclass,$term->slug,$term->name);
                $output .= sprintf($template,$buffer);
            }
            print $output;
        }
    }

    public function filterClasses($tax,$id = null) {
        if (empty($tax)) return;
        if (empty($id)) {
            global $post;
            $id = $post->ID;
        }
        $classes = wp_get_post_terms($id,$tax,array("fields" => "slugs"));
        if (is_array($classes) && ($count = count($classes)) > 0) {
            while($count--) {
                $classes[$count] = "filter-".$classes[$count];
            }
            echo join(" ",$classes);
        }
    }

    public function thumb($useFilters = true) {
        global $post;
        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
            $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,"thumbnail");
            if ($useFilters && has_filter("pe_post_thumbnail")) {
                echo apply_filters("pe_post_thumbnail",$thumb);
            } else {
                echo $thumb;
            }
        }
    }

    public function post_thumbnail_filter($data) {
        return $data;
    }

    public function hasFeatImage() {
        global $post;
        return @has_post_thumbnail($post->ID);      
    }

    public function get_origImage($id = null) {
        return wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($id));
    }

    public function resizedImg($w,$h,$custom = null) {
        $url = empty($custom) ? wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id()) : $custom;
        return $this->master->image->resizedImg($url,$w,$h);
    }

    public function img($w,$h = null,$custom = null) {
        $img = $this->resizedImg($w,$h,$custom);
        echo apply_filters("pe_theme_content_img",$img ? $img : "",$w,$h);
    }


    public function get_thumbImage($thumb) {
        if (@has_post_thumbnail()) {
            $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(),$thumb);
            return $thumb[0];
        }
        return "";
    }

    public function origImage() {
        echo $this->get_origImage();
    }

    public function excerpt() {
        the_excerpt();
    }

    public function content($text = null) {
        global $post;
        if (isset($post) && $post->post_type === "attachment") {
            echo apply_filters("wpautop",$post->post_excerpt);
        } else {
            the_content($text);
        }
    }

    public function builder() {
        if (post_password_required() || !PE_THEME_PLUGIN) {
            $this->content();
        } else {
            $meta =& $this->meta();
            if (empty($meta->builder)) return;

            global $post;
            $view = new PeThemeViewLayout();
            $conf = (object) 
                array(
                      "id" => $post->ID,
                      "settings" => $meta->builder
                      );

            $view->output($conf);
        }
    }

    public function hasMedia() {
        $format = $this->format();

        $meta =& $this->meta();
        $ret = false;

        switch ($format) {
        case "gallery":
            $gallery = empty($meta->gallery) ? false : $meta->gallery;
            $ret = !empty($gallery->id) && $gallery->id > 0;
            break;
        case "video":
            $video = empty($meta->video) ? false : $meta->video;
            $ret = !empty($video->id) && $video->id > 0;
            break;
        default:
            $ret = $this->hasFeatImage();
        }

        return $ret;
    }


    public function slider($w,$h) {
        if ($this->format() != "gallery") return;
        $meta =& $this->meta();
        $gallery = empty($meta->gallery) ? false : $meta->gallery;
        if (empty($gallery->id)) return;
        $view =& $this->master->view; 
        $conf = $view->create("SliderVolo","gallery",array("id" =>$gallery->id),$w,$h);
        $view->resize($conf);
    }


    public function media() {
        $format = $this->format();

        $meta =& $this->meta();

        switch ($format) {
        case "gallery":
            $gallery = empty($meta->gallery) ? false : $meta->gallery;
            if (!empty($gallery->id)) {
                $conf = 
                    $this->master->view->create(
                                                $gallery->type,
                                                "gallery",
                                                array("id" => $gallery->id),
                                                $gallery->width,
                                                $gallery->height
                                                );

                // use gallery caption
                $conf->caption = (object) array("title" => "ititle","description" => "caption");

                //$conf->caption->title = "ititle";
                //$conf->caption->description = "caption";

                $this->master->view->resize($conf);
            }


            break;
        case "video":
            $this->master->video->output();
            break;
        default:
            $format = $this->hasFeatImage() ? "image" : false;
        }

        return $format;
    }


    public function current($add = 0) {
        $page = $this->page;
        if ($page > 1) {
            $add += $this->qv["posts_per_page"]*($page-1);
        }
        echo $this->wpq->current_post + $add;
    }

    public function terms($tax,$sep = ",") {
        global $post;
        return join($sep,wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,$tax,array("fields" => "names")));
    }

    public function &getPostsQueryArgs($type,$count,$tax = null,$custom = null,$paged = false) {

        $args = array(
                      "post_type"=>"$type",
                      "posts_per_page"=>$count
                      );

        if ($tax) {
            $custom[$tax] = $this->terms($tax);
        }

        if (is_array($custom)) {
            $args = array_merge($args,$custom);
        }

        if ($paged) {
            $page = $this->page;
            $page = $page ? $page - 1 : 0;
            $args["offset"] = $count*$page;
        } else {
            // if pagination is not needed, avoid counting rows to boost performances
            $args['no_found_rows'] = true;
        }

        if ($args["post_type"] === "attachment") {
            $args["post_status"] = "inherit";
        }

        return $args;
    }

    public function getPostsLoop($type,$count,$tax = null,$custom = null,$paged = false) {

        $data = new StdClass();
        $args =& $this->getPostsQueryArgs($type,$count,$tax,$custom,$paged);

        $wpq = new WP_Query();
        $data->loop = $wpq->query($args);

        $loop =& $this->master->data->create($data,true);

        if ($paged) {
            $loop->pages = $wpq->max_num_pages;
        }

        return $loop;
    }

    public function customLoop($type,$count = 10,$tax = null,$custom = null,$paged = false) {
        $args =& $this->getPostsQueryArgs($type,$count,$tax,$custom,$paged);
        if ($this->current) {
            $this->loops[] = $this->current;
        }
        $this->master->data->postSave();
        $this->current = new WP_Query($args);
        return $this->current->post_count > 0;
    }

    public function related($type,$tax,$count) {
        //$settings = new StdClass();
        //$settings->post_type = "project";

        if ($loop = $this->customLoop($type,$count,$tax)) {
            get_template_part("related",$type);
            $this->resetLoop();
        }
    }


    public function resetLoop() {
        $this->master->data->postReset();
        $this->current = (count($this->loops) >0) ? array_pop($this->loops) : false;
    }

    public function blog($settings,$showpager = true) {
        global $post;

        $exclude = false;

        // prevents nested blogs
        if ($this->blogLoop) return;
        $this->blogLoop = true;

        // prevents loops
        if (isset($post) && $post) {
            $exclude = $post->ID;
        }

        if (is_string($settings) && !empty($settings)) {
            $id = $settings;
            $post = get_post($id);
            if (!$post) return;
            $meta = $this->master->meta->get($id,$post->post_type);
            if (empty($meta->blog)) return true;
            $settings = $meta->blog;
        }

        $settings = (object) shortcode_atts(
                                            array(
                                                  "layout" => "",
                                                  "count" => get_option("posts_per_page"),
                                                  "media" => "yes",
                                                  "pager" => "yes",
                                                  "sticky" => "yes",
                                                  "category" => "",
                                                  "tag" => "",
                                                  "format" => ""
                                                  ),
                                            (array) $settings
                                            );

        // prevents loops
        if ($exclude) {
            $custom = array("post__not_in" => array($exclude));
        }

        $custom["ignore_sticky_posts"] = ($settings->sticky === "no") ? 1 : 0;

        if ($settings->category) {
            $custom["category_name"] = $settings->category;
        }

        if ($settings->tag) {
            $custom["tag"] = $settings->tag;
        }

        if ($settings->format) {
            $tax_query = array(
                               array(
                                     'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                                     'field' => 'slug',
                                     'terms' => array("post-format-{$settings->format}")
                                     )
                               );
            $custom["tax_query"] = $tax_query;
        }

        $media = $settings->media === "yes";

        $this->customLoop("post",$settings->count,null,$custom,$settings->pager === "yes");

        $compact = compact("media");

        $this->master->template->get_part($compact,"loop",$this->have_posts() ? $settings->layout : "empty");

        if ($showpager && $settings->pager === "yes") {
            $this->pager();
        }

        $this->resetLoop();
        $this->blogLoop = false;

    }

    public function getPagerLoop($max = 5,$pages = false) {
        $pages = $pages ? $pages : $this->wpq->max_num_pages;
        if ($pages <= 1) return false;
        for ($p = 0;$p<$pages;$p++) {
            $links[] = get_pagenum_link($p+1);
        }
        return $this->master->data->createPager($this->page,$links,$max);
    }

    public function pager($class = "span12",$pages = false) {
        $loop = $this->getPagerLoop(5,$pages);
        if ($loop) $loop->main->class = $class;
        $this->master->template->paginate_links($loop);
    }


    public function comments() {
        comments_number('0','1','%');
    }

    public function body_class($class = "") {
        echo 'class="' . apply_filters("pe_theme_body_class",join( ' ', get_body_class( $class ) )) . '"';
    }


    public function total() {
        echo $this->wpq->found_posts;
    }

    public function hasNextPage() {
        $max = $this->wpq->max_num_pages;
        return ($max > 1 && $this->page < $max);
    }

    public function hasPrevPage() {
        $max = $this->wpq->max_num_pages;
        return ($max > 1 && $this->page > 1);
    }


    public function tagCloud($number,$orderby="name") {
        wp_tag_cloud(array("number"=>$number,"orderby"=>$orderby,"order"=>$orderby == "count" ? "DESC" : "ASC")); 
    }

    public function tags($sep = ", ",$tax = false) {
        if ($tax) {
            echo get_the_term_list(null, $tax, "", $sep, "");
        } else {
            the_tags("",$sep,"");
        }
    }

    public function category($prefix="") {
        if ($prefix) {
            echo "$prefix ";
        }
        the_category(", ");
    }

    public function date($prefix="") {
        if ($prefix) {
            echo "$prefix ";
        }
        the_time(get_option('date_format'));
    }

    public function author($prefix="") {
        if ($prefix) {
            echo "$prefix ";
        }
        the_author();
    }

    public function format($is_format = null) {
        global $post;
        $format = get_post_format($post->ID);
        return empty($is_format) ? $format : $format === $is_format;
    }

    public function pageTemplate($post_id = null) {
        if (function_exists("get_page_template_slug")) return get_page_template_slug($post_id);
        $post = get_post( $post_id ); 
        if ( 'page' != $post->post_type ) 
            return false; 
        $template = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true ); 
        if ( ! $template || 'default' == $template ) 
            return ''; 
    }

    public function slug() {
        global $post; 
        echo $post->post_name;
    }


    public function type() {
        global $post;
        return $post->post_type;
    }

    public function classes($add="") {
        $c = join(" ",get_post_class());
        $c = $add ? "$c $add" : "$c";
        printf('class="%s"',$c);
    }


    public function isVideo() {
        return get_post_format() === "video";
    }

    public function includeLoopPart($prefix="looped") {
        global $post;
        $type = $post->post_type;
        get_template_part("$prefix-$type",$this->format());
    }

    public function getBlogLink() {
        $pfp = get_option("page_for_posts"); 
        $pfp  = $pfp ? get_page_link($pfp) : "";

        return get_option('show_on_front') == 'page' ? $pfp : home_url();
    }

    public function wp_tag_cloud_filter($data) {
        if (is_tag()) {
            global $wp_query;
            $currentTagID = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->term_id;
            $data = str_replace("tag-link-$currentTagID","tag-link-$currentTagID current-tag",$data);
        }
        return preg_replace('/style=.[^"|\']+./i','',$data);
    }

    public function widget_tag_cloud_args_filter($args) {
        $options =& $this->master->options;
        $orderby = $options->get("tagCloudOrder");
        $args = array_merge($args,array("number"=>$options->get("tagCloudCount"),"orderby"=>$orderby,"order"=>$orderby == "count" ? "DESC" : "ASC"));
        return $args;
    }

    public function &meta($postID = FALSE) {
        global $post;
        //print_r($post);
        return $this->master->meta->get($postID ? $postID : ($post ? $post->ID : NULL),$post ? $post->post_type : "post");
    }

    public function strip_rel_filter($content) {
        return preg_replace('/rel="/','data-rel="',$content);
    }

    public function excerpt_more_filter($more) {
        return "";
    }

    public function the_content_more_link_filter($link) {
        //$link = sprintf('&nbsp;<a href="%s#more-%s" class="read-more">%s</a>',get_permalink(),$GLOBALS["post"]->ID,__("more",'Pixelentity Theme/Plugin'));
        $link = sprintf('&nbsp;<a href="%s" class="read-more">%s</a>',get_permalink(),__("more",'Pixelentity Theme/Plugin'));
        return $link;
    }

    public function edit_post_link_filter($link) {
        return str_replace("post-edit-link","label",$link);
    }


    public function getSocialLinks($links,$position = "top") {
        $html = "";
        if (is_array($links)) {
            foreach ($links as $link) {
                if (empty($link)) continue;
                list($icon,$tooltip) = explode("|",$link["icon"]);
                $html .= apply_filters("pe_theme_content_get_social_link",sprintf('<a href="%s" data-rel="tooltip" data-position="%s" data-original-title="%s"><i class="%s"></i></a>',$link["url"],$position,$tooltip,$icon),$link["url"],$tooltip,$icon);
            }
        }
        return $html;
    }

    public function socialLinks($links,$position = "top") {
        $html = apply_filters("pe_theme_social_links",$this->getSocialLinks($links,$position),$position);
        echo $html ? $html : "";
    }

    public function getPagesByTemplate($template) {

        $args = array();

        if ($template) {
            $args = 
                array(
                      'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
                      'meta_value' => "page-$template.php"
                      );                
        } 

        $pages = get_pages($args);
        return $pages;
    }

    public function getPagesLinkByTemplate($template) {
        $pages = $this->getPagesByTemplate($template);
        if (!is_array($pages)) return false;
        $links = false;
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $links[] = get_page_link($page->ID);
        }
        return $links;
    }

    public function getPagesOptionsByTemplate($template) {
        $pages = $this->getPagesByTemplate($template);
        if (!is_array($pages)) return false;
        $links = false;
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $links[$page->post_title] = $page->ID;
        }
        return $links;
    }

    public function getPageLinkByTemplate($template) {
        $pages = $this->getPagesLinkByTemplate($template);
        return $pages ? $pages[0] : "";
    }


    public function adjPost($previous = false) {
        $post = get_adjacent_post(false,"", $previous);
        $ret = "";
        if ($post) {
            $ret = new StdClass;
            $ret->title = get_the_title($post);
            $ret->link = get_permalink($post);
            $ret->date = get_the_time(get_option('date_format'), $post);
        }
        return $ret; 
    }

    public function breadcrumbs($sep = ' / ') {
        $template = '<a class="pe-breadcrumbs-%s" href="%s">%s</a>';
        $links[] = sprintf($template,'home',home_url(),__('Home','Pixelentity Theme/Plugin'));
        if (is_home()) {
            $links[] = sprintf($template,'blog','#',__('Blog','Pixelentity Theme/Plugin'));
        } elseif (is_category()) {
            $links[] = substr(get_category_parents(get_query_var('cat'),true,$sep), 0, -strlen($sep));
        } elseif (is_tag() || is_tax()) {
            $term = get_queried_object();
            if (!empty($term->term_id)) {
                $links[] = sprintf($template,'tax',get_tag_link($term->term_id),single_term_title("",false));
            }
        } elseif (is_archive()) {
            if ( is_day() ) {
                $date = get_the_date();
            } elseif ( is_month() ) {
                $date = get_the_date('F Y');
            } elseif ( is_year() ) {
                $date = get_the_date('Y');
            } else {
                $date = __("Archives",'Pixelentity Theme/Plugin');
            }
            $links[] = sprintf($template,'archive','#',$date);
        } elseif (is_page()) {
            global $post;
            if (!empty($post->ID)) {
                $parents = get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
                if (!empty($parents) && is_array($parents)) {
                    $parents = array_reverse($parents);
                    $parents[] = $post->ID;
                    $home = trailingslashit(home_url());
                    foreach ($parents as $id) {
                        $link = get_permalink($id);
                        if ($link == $home) continue;
                        $links[] = sprintf($template,'page',$link,get_the_title($id));
                    }
                }
            }
        } elseif (is_single()) {
            global $post;
            if (!empty($post->ID)) {
                $taxs = get_object_taxonomies($post,"names");
                if (!empty($taxs) && is_array($taxs)) {
                    while ($tax = array_shift($taxs)) {
                        if ($tax != "post_format") break; 
                    }
                    if ($tax) {
                        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID,$tax);
                        if (is_array($terms)) {
                            reset($terms);
                            $term = key($terms);
                            $parents = get_ancestors($terms[$term]->term_id,$tax);
                            $parents = is_array($parents) ? array_reverse($parents) : array();
                            $parents[] = $terms[$term]->term_id;
                            foreach ($parents as $id) {
                                $term = get_term($id,$tax);
                                $links[] = sprintf($template,'tax',get_term_link($term),$term->name);
                            }                               
                        }
                    }
                }
                $links[] = sprintf($template,'single',get_permalink($post->ID),get_the_title($post->ID));
            }
        }
        print join($links,$sep);
    }


    public function adjPostLink($previous = false) {
        $post = get_adjacent_post(false,"", $previous);
        return $post ? get_permalink($post) : "";   
    }

    public function prevPostLink() {
        return $this->adjPostLink(true);
    }

    public function nextPostLink() {
        return $this->adjPostLink(false);
    }

    public function linkPages() {
        wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __('Pages:','Pixelentity Theme/Plugin'), 'after' => '</div>'));
    }


}

?>
```

Comment: Why not add the function to the relevant theme files?

Comment: Since there's $t->content you could try $excerpt =& $t->excerpt; it's just a guess though

Comment: Or maybe $t->content->excerpt();

Comment: @rnevius Any idea which theme files I should be looking at and where the line should go?

Comment: It depends on which page(s) you want to display the excerpt...

Comment: @dubbcoast What do you mean by no luck? Any error? Where did you get the theme from?

Comment: @dubbcoast Found it. it's paid theme so can't really help without seeing the code. But i found that there's a file PeThemeContent.php so try look into it.

Comment: @molda Thanks so much. I found the file, but not sure what to do with it. That line I referenced is not there, but there is similar code... I reference the source in my original post. Thanks again!

Comment: @dubbcoast Ok cool, so this **$t->excerpt();** or **$t->content->excerpt();** should work and since it is actualy just a wrapper for **the_excerpt();** then you could simply use **the_excerpt();** if it doesn't work try **echo the_excerpt();**